# In Jason X, does his son have similar characertistics?

Tags: comics, friday-the-13th, jason-x

In the horror comic book series *Jason X*, The iconic slasher is re-imagined as an unstoppable cyborg in the future.

My question is does Jason's genetic son, Free Jefferson have his fathers abilities? More specifically regeneration and immortality. And would Jason be able to be reborn through Jefferson as he is a a Voorhees through blood?

Comment: Spoilers, mate... spoilers. Also, not sure about the comic, but in the movie "Jason X" (which it is presumably based on), Jason isn't "reimagined" - he's upgraded.

Comment: I have seen the movies however  i said re-imagined because in the comics Jason X (updated Jason) fights an organic version of Jason but later in the series I heard he had a child cloned from his DNA and that's were my question is. If this child has the same powers as him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [Free Jefferson](http://fridaythe13th.wikia.com/wiki/Free_Jefferson) has currently only shown up in one place, the tie-in novel, ''Jason X: to the Third Power''. I looked around a handful of reviews of the book and it appears that Free shows no special powers. It's also unknown whether Jason's powers would be transmitted either down his bloodline or through his genetics since it seems they are supernatural in nature, but might result from his distant ancestor, [Jebediah Voorhees](http://headhuntershorrorhouse.wikia.com/wiki/Jebediah_Voorhees#Jebediah_Voorhees), who possessed a copy of the Necronomicon and passed it on to his descendants.

It is also unknown whether he counts as "part of the bloodline" for the purpose of killing Jason.